# What is the proper way to hold your arms while training your biceps?

Tags: weightlifting, biceps

When I work out my biceps I do:

```
1: 4x15 chin ups (84 kg me)    
2: 4x15 barbell curls (30 kg)    
3: 4x12 concentration curls (22kg)       
4: 4x12 cable preacher curls (62 kg)
```

My problem is with my forearms ,they hurt badly when I start doing barbell curls but not while I am training but when I am done with each set of 15.

Is this a problem with how I am holding my arms?Am I using the wrong barbell maybe?Or my forearms just cant handle this much weight?

**EDIT:**

I realized I have this type of pain :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CudqmKQIRRA

Do you consider his tips viable to help with my problem?

Comment: Are you using the straight bar or the curved bar for barbell?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, none of those movements should elicit that type of response from your forearms. You should ask someone to check your form and possibly the amount of weight you are using.

Comment: @xCodeZone I am using a straight bar.

Comment: @rrirower I done a full medical test and I was in amazing form,but I think I am doing something wrong when I am trying to lift the barbell .Maybe because I am twisting my hand wrist a bit ?

Comment: @JohnPietrar: Awkward Wrist movements can lead to injuries. One such is golfers elbow. The cause mentioned for it for lifters is twisting the wrist a bit too much, or more than what your tendons can handle(It may not be your case, but I'm using it as a reference). I used to have wrist pains when I used curved bar as a beginner. I figured out that I wasn't holding or curling it the way I should. So, just ask someone to take a video of your wrist movements and see if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @rrirower - All of those exercises require grip strength to hold onto bars or handles, which means forearms.

Comment: Does the pain only occur after using the barbell? Or also after doing other biceps exercises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a thumbless grip on the bar if you want to carry on with palms facing up. Point your thumbs down the bar.
2. Use a Ez-curl bar (curved). This allows your palms to face more inwardly which helps.
3. Use a reverse grip, just turn your hands over.
4. Use dumbbells.

Answer (score 0):

Without more specifics on the type of pain you are feeling, it's difficult to say that there is a problem with the way you are holding your arms. However, unless you are twisting them in some peculiar way, I would suggest that due to the total amount of repetitions you are performing, that the pain is normal.

Comment: I am twisting my hand wrist a bit when I am trying to lift the barbel could that be something?

Answer (score 0):

One technique mentioned by strength coach Charles Poliquin is to do your curls with wrists extended down and back. It will feel a little weird and you may have to decrease the weight slightly but it ensures that *all* of the stress is on your elbow flexors. You may be able to extend the set my moving your wrists back to a normal position.
A more general piece of advice would be to make sure that you're doing some reverse curls or other exercise for your wrist extensors, so that you're not developing any imbalance in your forearms.